# JdbcMessageStore is not optimized for use in a 'MessageGroupQueue'

Tags: spring-integration

My Spring Integration project shows me such warnings during startup, however my application seems run well, anyone can tell me what this warnning is, and how to avoid it?

```
WARN  [main] MessageGroupQueue:92 - JdbcMessageStore is not optimized for use in a 'MessageGroupQueue'; consider using a `ChannelMessageStore'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it really works well, but you should be ready for slow processing.

The `JdbcMessageStore` interacts with 3 tables and its purpose is definitely for groups - aggregator, resequencer, delayer etc.

If you need the JDBC store for the `QueueChannel`, you should consider to switch to the `JdbcChannelMessageStore`. That is indeed optimized for queues and deals only with the single table in DB: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store-channels